# How to assign a value to a BOOL pointer in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm having a bit of a confusion on how to assign a value to a BOOL pointer? Here's my code:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    self.latitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    self.longitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

    if (!initialBroadcast) {
        initialBroadcast = YES; // Where I'm having troubles

        [broadcastTimer fire];
    };
}
```

The compiler keeps telling me this: `Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'BOOL *' (aka 'signed char *') from 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char')`.

I'd appreciate a clarification on this since I am a nubski.

---

**UPDATE**

As many of you have pointed out, I am apparently abusing the declaration of a `BOOL` by using a pointer for it. To be honest, I don't know why I used it, but since I'm new to Objective-C it must have worked for what I was doing so it stuck.

Anyway, I have since changed the declaration to:

```
//  In .h
@interface ... {
    BOOL initialBroadcast;
}

@property BOOL initialBroadcast;

//  In .m
@synthesize initialBroadcast;
```

So, am I on the right track now?

Comment: How is `initialBroadcast` declared?

Comment: Why do you need a pointer to a `BOOL`?

Comment: Because that's what I saw in other examples so I went with it and it seems to work. Ultimately I need a `BOOL` variable in my app delegate that I can check if the app had performed the initial broadcast of the device's location.

Comment: BOOL is a scalar type like int, NSUInteger, char, etc...  You don't declare it as a pointer type in all but very rare circumstances.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You need to say

```
*initialBroadcast = YES;
```

initialBroadcast is a pointer aka memory address.  The * gives access to the value at the memory address that the pointer holds.  So initialBroadcast is a memory address, but *initialBroadcast is a boolean or char.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I must say, Objective-C has been a steep learning curve for me, and it's not even because of complexity, but the very simple yet subtle things...

Comment: This is wrong. That shouldn't be a pointer type at all and, more likely than not, that code is going to crash because the OP doesn't malloc memory for storage anywhere.

Comment: It was not declared in the code, but the compiler error shows that it is indeed a pointer variable. It is true that it needs to be pointing to valid memory on the stack or the heap.

Comment: I agree this is wrong, Bool is not an object, so when you initialize you should not have * like explained below. * is only for object. When you don't have * in the initialization, you would just do initialBroadcast = Yes;

Comment: You are directly assigning an address to the initialBroadcast pointer rather than using indirection like for instance in this case- BOOL flag= YES; BOOL *initialBroadcast= &flag; Your piece of code will crash when dereference initialBroadcast pointer as it will try and access contents at an address (that you had directly assigned) which does not belong to your address space and is part of read-only section.

Answer (score 59):

The problem isn't the assignment, it is much more likely that you declared your instance variable to be `BOOL *initialBroadcast;`.

There is no reason to declare the instance variable to be a pointer (at least not unless you really do need a C array of BOOLs)..  Remove the * from the declaration.

As well, that will fix your currently incorrect if() test.  As it is, it is checking to see if the pointer is set, not the value.

Comment: There is no reason to declare the instance variable to be a pointer
----
Not so correct, in Xcode 4.4, you can use some new features like this:
`- (void)enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))block`
It use a pointer on `BOOL` type.

Comment: Sure, @Chris, but that has nothing to do with the OP's question.   That is a parameter to a block and has no relationship to an instance variable at all.

Answer (score 10):

Change -

```
initialBroadcast = YES;
```

to

```
(*initialBroadcast) = YES;
```

Since, you are assigning value to the location the pointer points to( assuming it is initialized ), `initialBroadCast` should be *dereferenced* first.

Answer (score 3):

Could be that you should write

```
*initialBroadcast = YES; // Where I'm having troubles
```

The line before seem to be a standard check to see that the pointer is valid (not nil)

Comment: So, does that mean that `if (!initialBroadcast)` checks for `nil` instead of `NO`? Since I'm coming from C#, I just want to check if `initialBroadcast` is `NO`, so is that right or wrong?

Comment: You are right. Wasn't thinking. It should have been `if (initialBroadcast)` to check that initialBroadcast isn't nil. Now it seems like initialBroadcast has to be zero (same as nil or NO). Which would make `*initialBroadcast = YES;` dangerous and cause a segmentation violation.

Comment: To check if it is NO you should write `if (*initialBroadcast == NO)` (being explicit) but that is dangerous, unless you are sure the pointer is correct.

Comment: Maybe you have mistakenly declared the initialBroadcast as `BOOL * initialBroadcast` where `BOOL initialBroadcast` would do. Do you allocate the BOOL somewhere?