# Is it good practice to avoid declaring a pointer to BOOL type in objective C?

Tags: objective-c

I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364506/how-to-assign-a-value-to-a-bool-pointer-in-objective-c) in stackoverflow.

The excerpt answer provided by bbum is below:

> The problem isn't the assignment, it is much more likely that you
>   declared your instance variable to be BOOL *initialBroadcast;.
>
> There is no reason to declare the instance variable to be a pointer
>   (at least not unless you really do need a C array of BOOLs).. Remove
>   the * from the declaration.

1.Is there anything wrong in using a pointer variable even when I do not have to maintain an array of BOOLs?

2.I think even if avoiding them a good practice, it is not specific to objective-C and applies to all programming languages which has pointers.

Please answer my questions.

Comment: It isn't discouraged, it isn't illegal, but it's just plain useless to most objC code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.Is there anything wrong in using a pointer variable even when I do not have to maintain an array of BOOLs?

It's not illegal to do so, but it is bad practice.  Using a pointer variable requires that you manage that memory (allocate and free it), and there are whole classes of bugs that can occur as a result.  If you forget to allocate the memory, or accidentally modify the pointer, your program could crash, or you could overwrite some other part of memory.  If you forget to free the memory, you have a memory leak.  None of these things can ever happen if you're just using a plain BOOL.  In addition, you get no benefit from using a pointer here; you do a bunch of extra work, and get nothing in return.

> 2.I think even if avoiding them a good practice, it is not specific to objective-C and applies to all programming languages which has
>   pointers.

I don't know about "all programming languages which [have] pointers", but I would certainly say in any C-based language (C, C++, Objective-C), it's bad practice to use pointers to intrinsic types when a plain variable of that type will do.  If you can avoid doing memory management, do so.

On a side note, it *is* good practice to listen to everything [bbum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25646/bbum) says.  Seriously.

Comment: A memory leak with a 32 bit signed char?  HA!

Comment: Actually, BOOL is a signed char.  Sure, leaking 1 byte is pretty inconsequential, but why not avoid it if you can?

Comment: I know, I know, but it's still funny!