# Weird warning issue when assigning a value to a BOOL pointer

Tags: ios, objective-c, boolean

I'm developing an in iOS6 and using Xcode 4.5.2.

I've a `UIViewController`,let's say its name is `aViewController`. In this `UIViewController`, i've a **BOOL pointer** declared as a property using this code. Actually, it's not a piece of code i've implemented, so i don't really know why **BOOL pointer** is used.

Now, when assigning a value to this **BOOL pointer**, i got this famous warning `Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'BOOL *' (aka 'signed char *') from 'signed char'` which is totally understandable because in my case,**BOOL** points to a boolean variable.

To resolve this problem, i've tried [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364506/how-to-assign-a-value-to-a-bool-pointer-in-objective-c).So my code was like this:

```
aViewController.aBoolPointer = YES;
```

Then, i've tried ,

```
aViewController.(*aBoolPointer) = YES;
```

As Objective-c is a super set of C, i remember that in C `.*` notation is equal to `->`. And the above notation gives an error.Error description : **Identifier expected** .

If i change code to like this :

```
aViewController->aBoolPointer = YES ;
```

I got this error **Instance variable aBoolPointer is protected**.

Here is the weird issue, if i use this code

```
aViewController.aBoolPointer = NO ;
```

Then, i got no warning.

So my questions are :

**1**-Why i got no warning when i assign **NO** value to a **BOOL pointer** ?

**2**-How can i properly assign **YES** value to **BOOL pointer** ?

**3**-What is the difference between **YES** or **NO** by considering the steps i explained ?

Thank you,all.

Comment: Why do you want a `BOOL *`?  I bet you simply want a `BOOL` property instead.  You've got confused because all objects in Obj-C are pointers and you've assumed primitive properties need to be pointers as well.

Comment: I've already explained in the question i didn't write this code, i've already knew that it's usually useless to use BOOL *, also, If u see this question link i attached, it's already explained that use of BOOL* is not necessary. But,it's very weird issue i confront.That's why i'm asking why this is happening

Comment: Downvoters : Do you have any reason !!!!! If u have, u are welcome to comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1 Why i got no warning when i assign NO value to a BOOL pointer ?

Because `NO` is the same as `0`, or `NULL`, so it's like assigning a `NULL` to the pointer, as in:

```
BOOL *p = NULL;
```

> 2 How can i properly assign YES value to BOOL pointer ?

If the property is defined as:

```
@property(assign, nonatomic) BOOL *boolp;
```

Then:

```
BOOL b = YES;
obj.boolp = &b;
```

> 3 What is the difference between YES or NO by considering the steps i explained ?

I don't understand the question.

Comment: It depends where `b` is declared.  It can be anywhere and the same mechanism is used.  Using `BOOL *` is pointless and rarely done, so it doesn't really matter.  It needs to be dropped ASAP.

Comment: It's all clear right now,third question is explained in the first answer.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

BOOL pointer is just pointer like others

```
if (aViewController.aBoolPointer != NULL)
    *(aViewController.aBoolPointer) = YES;
```

Still, I have no idea why a property will use BOOL pointer as type. Are you using some third-party framework? You better to check their documentation or ask the author.

Comment: That doesn't really work; that means that `aBoolPointer` must be initialised by doing something like `aBoolPointer = malloc(sizeof(BOOL))` or something?

Comment: depends. the object may malloc the memory for you already (and it should). you really need to check the doc or ask the author.

Comment: i didn't initialise aBoolPointer

Comment: the object may initialize it for you so you don't have to. read the source code to find out.

Comment: There is no value in a `BOOL *` (or an `int *`) given the difficulties managing it and the fact that the pointer + allocated memory > size of the primitive!